# Associativity of norms in inseparable extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $L/K$ and $E/L$ be finite extensions.
Let $α$ be an element of E.
Let $N_{E/K}(α)$ be the norm of $α$, i.e. the determinant of the regular representaion matrix of $α$.
It is well known that $N_{E/K}(α)$ $=$ $N_{L/K}(N_{E/L}(α))$ if $E/K$ is separable.
I tried to find a proof of this formula in inseparable extensions, but failed.
Where can I find it?
It'd be also nice if someone provides a sketch of the proof, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof can be found [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/676Page/handouts/normtrace.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice proof.

Comment: By the way, I think the proof of Lemma 1.1 in the above link is incorrect.

Comment: I found another proof. See my comments here(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50737/self-contained-reference-for-norm-and-trace ).